# failed building javascript bundle about @expo/vector-icons

Tags: react-native, expo

I use react-native-app and expo to build a project called UdaciFitness, but I come across some problems when I use 'import '@expo/vector-icon''
the error message in windows CMD is

```
17:41:21: Unable to resolve @expo/vector-icons" from "./C:\\Users\\acer\\WebstormProjects\\UdaciFitness\\node_modules\\expo\\src\\Icon.js"
17:41:21: Failed building JavaScript bundle
18:16:28: Unable to resolve @expo/vector-icons" from "./C:\\Users\\acer\\WebstormProjects\\UdaciFitness\\node_modules\\expo\\src\\Icon.js"
```

here is part of my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `@expo/vector-icons`. Run `yarn add @expo/vector-icons` in your project directory to add it to package.json and install the package. Then restart the Expo tools and load your project again.